# Returns dictionary string or 1 literal row in CSV. How to parse data into CSV?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

When this code runs without parsing it to a CSV it runs great and outputs a dictionary like so: `[{'word': 'veriff', 'count': 11076}, {'word': 'verif', 'count': 7773}, {'word': 'product', 'count': 6414}.............]`

What I need is to parse this so it returns the keywords "Word" and "count" in csv rows. The code I have implemented returns a literal row of Word and Count instead of the data.

I can't find an answer similar to mine, help would be appreciated.

How word and count are defined in the code:

```
  for w in sorted_words:
    if w[1] > 4:
        output['keywords'].append({
            'word': w[0],
            'count': w[1],
        })
```

Current Code:

```
import csv

site = 'https://www.microblink.com'
output = analyze(site)
keywords = output['keywords']['word']['count']
fields = ['word', 'count']

with open ('mbtest.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file: 
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)

    for keyword in keywords:
        keyword = keywords(["word"], keywords["count"])
        rows = keyword
        csvwriter.writerow(keyword)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy solution to print a dictionary to pretty print:

```
pip install pprintpp
```

/

```
import pprint
site = 'http://www.veriff.com'

output = analyze(site, analyze_headings=True, analyze_extra_tags=True)

pprint.pprint(output)
```